# Upload an Excel file as a background task in celery? - Celery Redis Python Django

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

**Problem** for `upload_subscribers.delay` parameters can only be integers or strings, I would not be able to pass `request` or `your_file` as a parameter into the function. How can I fix the below code so it can be run as a background task in celery?

```
import pandas as pd
from .models import Subscriber

def upload_subscribers(request):
    template = "audiences/upload.html"
    if request.method == "POST":
        your_file = request.FILES['file']

        if your_file.name.endswith('.xlsx'):
            df = pd.read_excel(your_file)

            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                created = Subscriber.objects.update_or_create(
                    email= row[2],
                    defaults = {
                        "first_name": row[0],
                        "last_name": row[1],
                    })

    return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two ways to solve this problem,

- Send entire data of the file as function argument
- Save the file in some storage system like Disk, S3, Database, etc, send this file location to the celery task.

```py
data = ""
with open(your_file, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
upload_subscribers.delay( data )
```

Comment: OK understood, I have implemented this through storage system. However, is your code above for "Sending entire data of the file as function argument"?  How can I convert data of an excel file into something that can be added as function argument, any info on this?

Comment: That's what the code does in this, it reads the `xls` data in `string` and sends as the function parameter. You would have to change reader, either save this data in the tmp xl file or use StringIo.